# Killing an unkillable Hyper-V image

Tags: hyper-v

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 Hyper-V image running on my Windows 10 box. Couple of days ago I saved the image and tried to restore it today. The restore operation hangs at around 10% complete.

This has turned into quite a blocker for me because it's put my machine into a bit of an unusable state. On startup Hyper-V immediately attempts to restore this image and vmwp kicks off and just starts taking up 100% CPU on one of my processors. I've tried every thing I can find on how to kill this VM and none of it is working

1. Cancel Restore: this has zero effect
2. Change the VM to not auto-start on machine startup: this configuration setting cannot be set while the VM is in the middle of restoring
3. Delete the VM on disk: can't do that while vmwp.exe is running on the image
4. Kill vmwp.exe: It's an unkillable process. First attempt at kill returns no error but every subsequent attempt generates an "Access Denied" error. Yes I'm killing from an elevated window.

I'm essentially out of ideas at this point on how to recover. I've looked at a lot of articles on how to handle this but they all recommend ideas I've already tried. Hoping there is a way to recover besides paving my machine here.

Answer (score 3):

A coworker had an idea that worked here. Disable VT-x in the BIOS during reboot. That will effectively stop Hyper-V from starting. That allowed me to kill the VM.